# Dot product in pyspark dataframes with MLLIB

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a very simple dataframe in pyspark, something like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import DenseVector

row = Row("a", "b")
df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([
    offer_row(DenseVector([1, 1, 1]), DenseVector([1, 0, 0])),
]).toDF()
```

and I would like to compute the dot product of these vectors without resorting to a UDF call.

The spark MLLIB [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html) references a `dot` method on `DenseVectors` but if I try to apply this as follows:

```
df_offers = df_offers.withColumn("c", col("a").dot(col("b")))
```

I get errors like:

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

Does anyone know if these mllib methods are able to be called on DataFrame objects?

Answer (score 1):

Here, you're applying the `dot` method on a column and not on a `DenseVector`, which indeed does not work :

```
df_offers = df_offers.withColumn("c", col("a").dot(col("b")))
```

You will have to use an udf :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array
from pyspark.sql.types import DoubleType

def dot_fun(array):
    return array[0].dot(array[1])

dot_udf = udf(dot_fun, DoubleType())

df_offers = df_offers.withColumn("c", dot_udf(array('a', 'b')))
```

Comment: It blows my mind that Spark developers have not developed a way around this yet.

Comment: All I am getting for now is: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dot'`. And even if I call `np.dot(a, b)`, there is always an error with types.

Answer (score 1):

As a remark to the first answer, all I am getting for now is: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'dot'`.

And even if I call `np.dot(a, b)`, there is always an error with types. Something like:

`Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 225.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: ... : net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.dtype)`

I had to change return value to item(), so that it is not in numpy anymore. Working solution:

```
@F.udf(returnType=T.FloatType())
def dot_udf(arr1, arr2):
    if arr1 is not None and arr2 is not None:
        return np.dot(arr1, arr2).astype(np.float32).item()

df_ = df.withColumn("c", dot_udf(F.col('a'), F.col('b')))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not. You'll have to use an udf:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

@udf("double")
def dot(x, y):
    if x is not None and y is not None:
        return float(x.dot(y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can multiply two columns without using UDF by first converting them into BlockMatrix and multiplying them like the example below

```py
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import IndexedRow, IndexedRowMatrix

ac = offer_row.select('a')
bc = offer_row.select('a')
mata = IndexedRowMatrix(ac.rdd.map(lambda row: IndexedRow(*row)))
matb = IndexedRowMatrix(bc.rdd.map(lambda row: IndexedRow(*row)))

ma = mata.toBlockMatrix(100,100)
mb = matb.toBlockMatrix(100,100)

ans = ma.multiply(mb.transpose())
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack but might be more performant than a Python udf. You could just convert the dot product into SQL:

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

coefs = pd.Series({'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0})
dot_sql = ' + '.join(
    '{} * {}'.format(coef, colname)
    for colname, coef
    in coefs.items()
)
dot_expr = expr(dot_sql)

df.withColumn('dot_product', dot_expr)
```