# Dot product between two Vector columns of a DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I do have this situation, and I'm stuck, and looking for guidance please *(I do see a lot of the limitations when performing linear algebra operations on Spark and one is distributed scientific computing like scipy and numpy at scale, serialization and deserialization)*, did thought of the joining this 2 column and perform a combination of columns and took a look of this approach, but index of the vector in vector column is very important for me and I also did look at this [udf for dot product for dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55957504/2027457) but is performing elements in to row and not all combinations from col1 with col2:

> "Looking to solve 2 product between 2 SparseVectors columns, one
> SparseVectors Column is from df1 and another is SparseVectors column
> from df2 with preserving the index of each vector". As u already know this is sole for big data, millions and billions vectors and collecting and using simple numpy and scipy is not a solution for me at this moment and only after filtering to have a small data.

Here is a sample of my data, each vector length is the same but the column (amount of vectors for each df are different :

```
> df1:

col1
|(11128,[0,1,2,3,5...|
|(11128,[11,22,98,...|
|(11128,[51,90,218...|

> df2:

col1
|(11128,[21,23,24,...|
|(11128,[0,1,2,3,5...|
|(11128,[0,1,2,3,4...|
|(11128,[28,59,62,...|
...
```

> **Adding more info for vectors part**, maybe modifying **.withColumn()** to use **.map()** function to do all vectors in parallel at once, since does have index? I do know is not the best
> approach but is all I can think of it right now (this is not related
> solve for **.dot()** product but more for the **UDF/pandas_udf** to
> extend math operations at **Vectors** level:

I do bring all into rdd with index, is a way for me to modify the approach to make index as col name ?

```
[[0, SparseVector(11128, {0: 0.0485, 1: 0.0515, 2: 0.0535, 3: 0.0536, 5: 0.0558, 6: 0.0545, 7: 0.0558, 59: 0.1108, 62: 0.1114, 65: 0.1123, 68: 0.1126, 70: 0.113, 82: 0.121, 120: 0.1414, 149: 0.149, 189: 0.1685, 271: 0.1876, 275: 0.1891, 303: 0.1919, 478: 0.2193, 634: 0.2359, 646: 0.2383, 1017: 0.2626, 1667: 0.2943, 1821: 0.3006, 2069: 0.3095, 2313: 0.3191, 3104: 0.347})], 
    [1, SparseVector(11128, {11: 0.0621, 22: 0.0776, 98: 0.1167, 210: 0.155, 357: 0.1811, 360: 0.1818, 466: 0.1965, 475: 0.1962, 510: 0.2005, 532: 0.2033, 597: 0.2092, 732: 0.2178, 764: 0.2198, 1274: 0.2489, 1351: 0.2519, 1353: 0.2522, 1451: 0.2562, 1577: 0.2608, 2231: 0.2841, 2643: 0.2969, 3107: 0.3114})]]
```

> So I did try approach with UDF but so far I can get with static vector
> (I convert to rdd and take each vector individually but is not the
> best approach for me, I want to do all at once and in parallel so map
> and keep the index for each vector in place when doing it):

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import *
# write our UDF for .dot product
def dot_prod(a,b):
    return a.dot(b)

# apply the UDF to the column
df = df.withColumn("dotProd", udf(dot_prod, FloatType())(col("col2"), array([lit(v) for v in static_array])))
```

Comment: Have you consider MLlib? https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.linalg

Comment: I would edit without numpy, I just provided one of the option. Here is the doc I do use [linalg doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector.dot)